RTL text doesn't work properly in an align environment with babel
I use babel to write Hebrew documents with Latex and I encountered a weird problem. Usually, I can use \text{} with Hebrew text inside math mode just fine. However, when I try to do that in an align environment, it just doesn't work. My sample code:
\documentclass{article}

\PassOptionsToPackage{no-math}{fontspec}
\usepackage[bidi=basic, layout=tabular, headfoot=hebrew]{babel}

\babelprovide[main, import, alph=letters, Alph=letters]{hebrew}
\babelprovide[import]{english}

\babelfont[hebrew]{rm}{Assistant}
\babelfont[hebrew]{sf}{Assistant}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
    A_n = \begin{cases}
        0 & \text{\( n \) זוגי} \\
        n & \text{\( n \) אי-זוגי}
    \end{cases}
\end{equation*}

\begin{align*}
    A_n = \begin{cases}
        0 & \text{\( n \) זוגי} \\
        n & \text{\( n \) אי-זוגי}
    \end{cases}
\end{align*}
\end{document}

Compiling this code fails with many weird errors and warnings:

A weird result I found by playing with this code is that if I replace the font to David CLM:
\babelfont[hebrew]{rm}{David CLM}
\babelfont[hebrew]{sf}{David CLM}

then I don't get errors, but the text is reversed:
]
I believe it's a problem with the align environment and not necessarily with the fonts since using an equation environment (or simply \[ \]) works and gives the correct result.
Can anybody explain why this happens and how I can fix this?

As a work around (if you don't require equation numbers),  \[ \begin{aligned} ... \end{aligned} \] seems to give the correct (at least the same as \begin{equation*} ... \end{equation*}) output.

I don't know about the font problem, as I don't have Assistant installed, but I think the directionality problem is basically the same as in here.

Try with \localebox, ie, \text{\localebox{...}}, as suggested by Udi Fogiel (see the link). Either use a recent version or copy the definition in the linked issue.
